# how to create tabbed pane gui using glade

Tags: gtk, gtk3, glade

Can any one tell how to create tabbed pane using glade, im using glade 3.6.7, with gtk+2 library
Is it possible in glade or, are there any gtk API's which allows to create tabbed panes

Comment: What do you mean by tabs? [This?](http://coding.debuntu.org/system/files/images/gtk-notebook-with-custom-tabs.png) If so, that's called a "notebook" in GTK+ terminology.

Comment: oh thanks notebook works in my case

Answer (score 3):

In GTK+ 3 it is called a `GtkNotebook` and you can find it in the category `Containers`.

(This answer is based on andlabs comment. I checked correctness in glade.)